# SharePoint 2010 Configuration wizard fails at step 2

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, central-administration, installation, configuration-wizard

We have installed SharePoint 2010 on one of our local Dev server. The issue that we are facing is during running configuration wizard.

When i start running configuration wizard it fails at step 2 with the below error:

```
01/07/2014 14:45:35  10  ERR              Task configdb has failed with an unknown exception 
01/07/2014 14:45:36  10  ERR              Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service SPUserCodeV4 on computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Win32.SPAdvApi32.StartService(String strServiceName)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWindowsServiceInstance.Start()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUserCodeServiceInstance.EnsureServiceInstance(SPFarm farm, SPServer server, SPServerRole role)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Join()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

I am not able to figure out the issue:

I also tried to start SPUserCodeV4 service but also unable to do so.

Anyone have any idea on this.

Thanks,